# Exponential of SparsePauliOp in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit

Since `qiskit.opflow` has been deprecated, the way I used to generate a UCC ansatz was to use `(Parameter('t') * Pauli('some Pauli')).exp_i()`. Now this is not possible, and I am unsure how to exponential my `SparsePauliOp`. If I have a parameterized `SparsePauliOp` such as `SparsePauliOp(['XZ', 'YZ'], coeffs=[ParameterExpression(1.0*a), ParameterExpression(1.0*b)])` for some `a, b = Parameter('a'), Parameter('b')`, how do I exponentiate this to get `exp(-i(XZ*a + YZ * b))` which I could then Trotterize to decompose into gates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [PauliEvolutionGate](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.PauliEvolutionGate.html). The UCC from Qiskit Nature in based on Qiskit's [EvolvedOperatorAnsatz](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.EvolvedOperatorAnsatz.html) which in turn is built using PauliEvolutionGate.

There is also a migration guide done as `opflow` was deprecated, which has a section on [evolution](https://qiskit.org/documentation/migration_guides/opflow_migration.html#evolutions).